# Expectation of X^2 using indicators

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

The question given is:

> Suppose you own n unique pairs of socks, each pair with a different pattern. In the first
> morning of the semester, you grab $2$ socks chosen randomly without replacement from
> the pile of $2n$ socks, and wear them for the day. The next day, you grab a new random
> pair from the $2n − 2$ remaining socks, and so on, until all socks are dirty.
> Let X be the number of days on which you wear correctly matched socks,
> based on the setting provided above. Find $E(X^2).$

I proceeded by defining the random variable X as the sum of indicators $I_1 + I_2 \cdots + I_n,$ where $I_i$ represents the indication that we had a match on day $i.$ Since $E(X^2)$ is essentially $E(\left(I_1 + I_2 +\cdots + I_n)^2\right),$ it simplifies down to $E(X) + n(n-1) (I_i I_j)$, where $I_i$ and $I_j$ for distinct i and j represent the indication that both pairs are found to be matching.

I calculated the probability of $I_i I_j$ as $6/((2n-1)(2n-3))$, however the given answer says that the corresponding probability is 1/((2n-1)(2n-3)). I feel like that is in correct because they forgot to multiply by the permutations of of picking 4 socks where we have two matching pairs. Is my intuition right or is the solution correct and why?

Comment: Your 6, how it came up? (The book is correct btw.)

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume $i < j.$ The way to to the calculation is $E(I_i I_j) = P(I_i = 1, I_j = 1) = P(I_j = 1\mid I_i = 1) P(I_i = 1)$ and $P(I_i = 1)$ is just having a correct pair on day $i$ *without any regard of any of the other days.* Therefore,
$$
P(I_i = 1) = \dfrac{\dbinom{n}{1}}{\dbinom{2n}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{2n-1}.
$$
Similarly, $P(I_j = 1 \mid I_i = 1)$ is essentially the same except that now you know that before the $j$th day, there was a day that had one math and *do not know whether there were other matches other days.* Therefore, this is an afresh experiment with $n-1$ replacing $n$ and so
$$
P(I_j = 1 \mid I_i = 1) = \dfrac{1}{2n-3}.
$$
The result follows.

Comment: "is essentially the same except that now you know that before the th day..." Technically, you know that on a specific day, not that on some day before the $j$th day. If all you knew was on some day, that would be considerably less information, I think.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is also probably true, and furthermore, my first remark that the $I_k$ are identically distributed is already somewhat difficult to prove (induction most likely). The calculation of the joint distributions $(I_s, I_t)$ is even harder, I think. I have never seen these problems tackled formally, always just appeal to intuition.

Comment: That they are identically distributed is relatively easy to prove, but, of course, they are not independent.

Comment: Thank you so much that clears up a lot of misconceptions!